# how to use razor as user control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Example Scenario:

Let's say I need to create a user control which displays a list of products for specified category (CategoryID passed as input to Index GET controller).

Also, it has a "Add" button below list which calls Category Details (GET) controller (passing categoryID to controller) which displays a form with Text box and button to add new category.

Once user enters category Details and press submit, Details (POST) controller is called which saves data and should redirect user back to page from where it was called.

This user control (razor file) can be used multiple times on same page.

**Queries**

1) What is best approach to integrate such a control in page views such that form in every user control is self contained and doesn't conflicts with other instances of same user control in same page?

2) I tried `Html.RenderAction("Index","Category",new {categoryName = "toys"})`
This works well in displaying category and clicking on Add button does takes user to "Add a new category" page. Problem is, what code should I write such that I can take user back to the same view page, where the user control was embedded (even better if I can scroll window to the position where control was placed)?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Data is posted in a partial view to the corresponding Action , It has no context of the main view/action. So we can post data to the main action so that modelstate is preserved and can be validated.

But if you want to post data to the partial view/action, we can redirect to main view/action post product is added.(But if some invalid data is entered, we cannot display any validation error)

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddProduct(string productId,string returnUrl)
{
  //Add product

return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if redirection to returnUrl is best way, but it solved my problem. In my ViewModel, I added a property of returnURL which I set to UrlRefrrer.ToString() when displaying form, while use that value to redirect when httpPost executes. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a partial view, namely an editor template.

In your Views folder, create a Shared folder and inside that create an EditorTemplates folder. From there create a strongly typed partial view named the same as the part of the model.

Then on your main view call `EditorFor`.